# Coreldraw X7 custom docker in VS 2013 gives error "Retrieving the com class factory for component with CLSID..."

Tags: vb.net, com, coreldraw

I have created a wpf class library project in visual studio 2013 for made custom docker in CorelDraw X7.I have give reference to assemby Corel.Interop.VGcore when importing a file on button click event but getting error "Retrieving the com class factory for component with CLSID...".

Operating System : WIN 7 64-bit
Visual Studio 2013
CorelDraw X7 64-bit

I have set target cpu properties in compile to Any CPU. I have read another answer that say changing target cpu to X86 will solve this problem but my all control disappears (Docker goes blank) when I change to X86.

my code is as below and attached error snapshot.

```
Public Class DockerUI

Private corelApp As Corel.Interop.VGCore.Application

Sub New(ByVal corelApp As Corel.Interop.VGCore.Application)
InitializeComponent()
Me.corelApp = corelApp
End Sub

Private Sub btnStartPro_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnStartPro.Click
Dim importfile As New ImportFilter
importfile = corelApp.ActiveLayer.ImportEx("D:\Logo.cdr", cdrFilter.cdrAutoSense, importfile)
End Sub
```

End Class
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHRID.jpg)